# VS 2010 Wcf client utility to my project?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have my **own** wcf program which is **not** WCF project  , and i want to trun the **built in** client testing tool for **my** app.

**How** do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to launch WCF Test Client without running visual studio, do the following:

> You can also invoke the WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe) outside
>   Visual Studio to test an arbitrary service on the Internet. To locate
>   the tool, go to the following location:
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
>
> To use the tool, double-click the file name to open it from this
>   location, or launch it from a command line.
>
> WCF Test Client takes an arbitrary number of URIs as command line
>   arguments. These are the URIs of services that can be tested.
>
> wcfTestClient.exe URI1 URI2 …
>
> After the WCF Test Client window is opened, click File->Add Service,
>   and enter the endpoint address of the service you want to open.

source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

**FYI**, I did a **Google** search with the phrase *run wcf test client* to find the article.